# Excel - Using nested IF COUNTIF to find count of 3 values within range, and if they are less than or greater than a static number

Tags: excel, if-statement, countif

In column K, I have some data categorized by 3 different values : Rent, Stacked, Available

What I am attempting to do is put together a formula that will get me a count of each of these, and then figuring out if they are less than, or greater than a number that we will set as the "threshold". I think there's something with the nested IF statements that aren't allowing it to work.

Reading it out the formula should go like this - if the count of "rent" is greater than 30, than it is outside of threshold, otherwise if the count of "stacked" is greater than 30, than it is outside of threshold, otherwise if the count of "available" is greater than 40, than it is outside of threshold, but if none of these are outside of the threshold, than they are within threshold.

Currently what i have is this:
`=IF(COUNTIF($K:$K,"Rent")>30,"Outside Thresh",IF(COUNTIF($K:$K,"Stacked")>30,"Outside Thresh",IF(COUNTIF($K:$K,"Availble")>40,"Outside Thresh","Within Thresh")))`

This seems simple enough, but I don't know if I've overthought it so much that now I can't figure it out.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It works when I copy paste the formula into a cell? See if you didn`t make a type with "Availble"

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot to mention that in the data that I have at the moment, under Column K I have: 31 Rent values, 29 Stacked values, and 66 Available values. 

The results for this should be:

-Rent: Outside Thresh
-Stacked: Within Thresh
-Available: Outside Thresh

Answer (score 0):

=IF(COUNTIF($K:$K,"Rent")>30,"Rent Outside Thresh","Rent within Thesh")&IF(COUNTIF($K:$K,"Stacked")>30," Stacked Outside Thresh"," Stacked within Thresh")&IF(COUNTIF($K:$K,"Availble")>40," Available Outside Thresh"," Available Within Thresh")

Why not put the code in 3 different cells?

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I was trying to avoid, just to have it all read from one column, but I may have to go that route. I did try your formula above, and came to this output:

"Rent Outside Thresh Stacked within Thresh Available Within Thresh"

Comment: That is what you wanted right? You can also change the “within thresh” to “”. Then it will only show if it is outside. This way it might be a little bit less messy

Comment: If the available is not correct, it is probably due to the typo